# Using webbrowser component to click button's website

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have seen some examples but nothing works for my problem.

Say you have in a website this html code.

```
<button onclick="searchClick();" value="SomeValue" type="button" class="submitBtn"><span>Some Button Text</span></button>
```

How can i retrieve this and perform click using the WebBrowser .NET Component in winforms?

Can't get nothing with GetElementById...or can't seem to find how to use the GetElementsByTag...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What examples have you seen? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button does not have an identifier. You need to analyses the page to find the uniqueness in the HTML such as the first button in a named form or the only button whose onclick attribute is "searchClick();", then write code to look for the uniqueness.

As for ciicking, programmatically clicking does not raise the onclick event. But you can call the searchClick function directly by using HtmlWindow.ExecScript.

Comment: How do i find the only button whose onclick attribute is searchClick() ? I can't seem to find HtmlWindow.ExecScript on the webbrowser component.

Comment: Thanx, found it on WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript() method and is working for me.